# How to Import/Export View Class Controllers in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I'm in desperate need of help.  How would I save a piece of memory and then load it back up? Basically I need to be able to open an app and start where I left off at.

Any advice/wisdom on how to get started?

All the thanks in the world!

Comment: See [iOS App Programming Guide - State Preservation and Restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should go with `NSUserDefaults` to save the current state.

Answer (score 0):

check this [state-preservation-and-restoration](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2013/05/21/state-preservation-and-restoration.html) , this helped me a lot in my application.

Answer (score 0):

When you are saying that you need to save a piece of memory, it depends on that piece, how to say it.

I would list down general methods being followed to save some data in app:

1. **NSUSerDefaults** If you want to save some data, like configuration data, some values/ keys /authentication, this would be best way to go for.
2. **CORE DATA** When you want to save some persistent data, objects or entries, heavy transactional data, go for core data.
3. **state preservation & restoration** If you want to save some UI related stuff, such that next time user opens app, he should see this n that, Go for state preservation & restoration.

To be more specific, or if you want detailed explanation, let me know which type of data you want to store in your app.. Happy to help ..:)